# Raspberry Pi to decode and encode TV

Tags: streaming-video, television-tuner

Is there a way for a Raspberry Pi to decode a TV signal coming through an antenna cable and vice versa: encode a video signal (from the internet) and display this on a TV with an antenna connection?

Comment: The pi can decode both mpeg2 and mpeg4 in hardware. I’ve done it with transport streams

Answer (score 0):

Hardware to perform all of these tasks is available from [SUNRAISE](http://www.sunriase.com) as USB modules. Integration with whichever Pi OS you're using is possible. More details are really required from you, to be more specific as to how to do the job.